# vim set scrollbind one page up/down in split view

Tags: vim, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to scrollbind 3 split views in "one page up / current page / one page down" relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like a charm.

```
noremap <silent> ZC :<C-U>let @z=&so<CR>:set so=0<CR>maHmz:set noscb<CR>
                  \:vs<CR>:vs<CR><C-W>wLzt<C-W>wLztLzt
                  \:set scb<CR><C-W>p:set scb<CR><C-W>h:set scb<CR>
                  \`zzt`a:let &so=@z<CR>
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/ZMRqDwxXMAM